# Setting content-disposition free text using libcurl in multi post using curl_formadd

Tags: libcurl

How I can set content-disposition whole text using libcurl in multi post using curl_formadd
e.g

set this for one part in multi/part http post.

Content-Disposition: form-data; name="UploadFile" filename="text.zip"
Thanks,
Naeem

Answer (score 1):

You cannot "set the whole text" using [curl_formadd](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/curl_formadd.html)().

curl_formadd() just creates and adds a struct to a linked list of 'struct curl_httppost' structs, and that linked list is what passes instructions to libcurl. You can build and populate such a linked list yourself and then you can set the text to whatever you like.